# Adding a object to a linked list at the end but always resulting into an error when a 2nd object is passed thru

Tags: java, list

I'm working on this method with linked list.
It's a method that add's an object at the end of the list.

I've got a problem when adding a second object in the linked list.

It gives me a NullPointerException at the while :

while (this.actual.getNext() != null)

I can't see what's wrong and i've been on this for an hour doing junits tests.

Any help ?

here's the complete code :

```
public boolean addEnd(T element) {
    boolean res = false;
    this.actual = this.head;

    if (element != null) {
        if (this.actual == null) {
            this.head= new Node<T>(element);
            res = true;
            nbElm++;
        } else if (!hasElement(element)) {
            while (this.actual.getNext() != null) { //Gives me an error NullPointeException
                this.actual = this.actual.getNext();
            }
            Node<T> next = new Node<T>(element);
            this.actual.setNext(next);
            res = true;
            nbElm++;
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this `addEnd` method, I think `this.actual` has no reason of being an instance variable. It should be a local variable of the method. Being an instance variable may cause other methods that use it to interfere with `addEnd`. I'm guessing `hasElement` modifies this variable, causing `this.actual` to become `null` before the start of your `while` loop.